# Beamerclass not showing tikz paths as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer

I tried the following codesnipped:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node} = [draw, align=center,circle, scale = 0.5, thick]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\tikz\node (n1) {N1}; &
& 
\tikz\node (n2) {N2}; \\
& 
\tikz\node (n3) {N3};& 
\tikz\node (n4) {N4}; \\
\tikz\node (n5) {N5}; & 
\tikz\node (n6) {N6}; & 
\tikz\node (n7) {N7};\\
\end{tabular}

\path<1>[blue,->] (n1.south) edge [out= 60, in= 135] (n2.north west);
\path<2>[red,->] (n1.south) edge [out=-70, in=-110] (n3.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

i does not behave as i expect it to. The paths do not get placed at the nodes but rather somewhere strange.

[image]

How can i fix this and still arrange the notes neatly like they are arranged now?

Comment: are you sure this has anything to do with `beamer`? I tried your code in an `article` and got the same 'unexpected' result...

Comment: The reason is due to a few problems. First tabular inside a tikzpicture should not work due to various text resets. So you need to take the tabular out. But then you still need to reference each individual tikzpicture and those require the `remember picture,overlay` mechanism or you can search for tikzmark word on this site. Lastly you might be better off if you just use a `matrix` node with one tikzpicture in one shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the perfect job for a `matrix of nodes`. Be warned however that inserting tikz matrices in a beamer frame require the `[fragile]` option.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node} = [draw, align=center,circle, scale = 0.5, thick]
\node[draw=none, matrix of nodes, row sep=1em, column sep=1em] (N) {
N1 &    & N2 \\
   & N3 & N4 \\
N5 & N6 & N7 \\
};
\path<1>[blue,->] (N-1-1.south) edge [out= 60, in= 135] (N-1-3.north west);
\path<2>[red,->]  (N-1-1.south) edge [out=-70, in=-110] (N-2-2.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this the result:

[image: Result]

Note that the code only gives a name `(N)` to the `\matrix` node. Automatically all the cells of the matrix have also a name, which is the name of the matrix followed by the row and column number.

You can also give particular names to some of the nodes, using the following syntax:

```
\node[draw=none, matrix of nodes, row sep=1em, column sep=1em] (N) {
|(N1)| N1 &           & |(N2)| N2 \\
          & |(N3)| N3 & |(N4)| N4 \\
|(N5)| N5 & |(N6)| N6 & |(N7)| N7 \\
};
\path<1>[blue,->] (N1.south) edge [out= 60, in= 135] (N2.north west);
\path<2>[red,->]  (N1.south) edge [out=-70, in=-110] (N3.south);
```

In each cell you can specify anything between `|` and that is passed to the `\node` being built. You can use this also to pass `[options]`.

Comment: If you switch to `ampersand replacement=\&` and use `\&` as the column separator you can skip the `fragile` requirement.